# Angularjs - ui-router sharing data between views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a list that show all top level objects, then you click on a parent object, and the view change to next state that is the child object that belongs to the parent.

I have a third state that i want to show the child object itself, not a list.

Demo is almost ready(i guess): http://plnkr.co/edit/6pqT0F?p=preview

When i click playlist1>playlist.singleCategory1 i want to show id: '1', title: 'Playlist1.singleCategory1'

Services:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

    .service('PlaylistsService', function($q) {
        return {
        playlists: [
          { id: '1', title: 'Playlist1',
              singleCategory: [
                { id: '1', title: 'Playlist1.singleCategory1' },
                { id: '2', title: 'Playlist1.singleCategory2' },
                { id: '3', title: 'Playlist1.singleCategory3' }
              ]
            },
            { id: '2', title: 'Playlist2',
              singleCategory: [
                { id: '1', title: 'Playlist2.singleCategory1' },
                { id: '2', title: 'Playlist2.singleCategory2' },
                { id: '3', title: 'Playlist2.singleCategory3' }
              ]
            },
            { id: '3', title: 'Playlist3',
              singleCategory: [
                { id: '1', title: 'Playlist3.singleCategory1' },
                { id: '2', title: 'Playlist3.singleCategory2' },
                { id: '3', title: 'Playlist3.singleCategory3' }
              ]
            }
        ],
        getPlaylists: function () {
          return this.playlists
        },
        getPlaylist: function(playlistId) {
          var dfd = $q.defer()
          this.playlists.forEach(function(playlist) {
            if (playlist.id === playlistId) dfd.resolve(playlist)
          })

          return dfd.promise
        }
      }
    })
```

Controllers:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
})

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, playlists) {
  $scope.playlists = playlists
})

.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, playlist) {
  $scope.playlist = playlist
})

.controller('SingleCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.services', 'starter.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.search', {
      url: "/search",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "search.html"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.browse', {
      url: "/browse",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "browse.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.playlists', {
      url: "/playlists",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "playlists.html",
          controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl',
          resolve: {
            playlists: function(PlaylistsService) {
              return PlaylistsService.getPlaylists()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.playlist', {
      url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "playlists.playlist.html",
          controller: 'PlaylistCtrl',
          resolve: {
            playlist: function($stateParams, PlaylistsService) {
              return PlaylistsService.getPlaylist($stateParams.playlistId)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .state('app.single', {
      url: "/playlists/:playlistId/:singleId",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "playlists.playlist.single.html",
          controller: 'SingleCtrl'
        }
      }
    });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/playlists');
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what problem you are having?

Comment: did you see the demo plunker? I have a third state that i want to show the child object itself, not a list. In my playlists.playlist.single.html i want to show the object. like this {{single.title}}.. sorry that i can't explain better, i hope you understand. EDIT: when i click playlist1>playlist.singleCategory1 i want to show id: '1', title: 'Playlist1.singleCategory1'

Comment: use `$stateParams` to get the playlistId and fetch that particular single details from the service and display.

Comment: @Jess I've updated my answer with a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SingleCtrl, you must get the playlistId from the `stateParams` and again fetch that particular element from the service.

I've implemented it like below:

In your controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ["starter.services"])

    .controller('SingleCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, PlaylistsService) {
      PlaylistsService.getSingle($stateParams.playlistId, $stateParams.singleId).then(function(data){
        $scope.single = data;
      })
    });
```

In your service : I've created another method called `getSingle` which will take both playlistid and singleId to fetch that particular object.

```
getSingle: function(playlistId, singleId) {
          var dfd = $q.defer();
           this.getPlaylist(playlistId).then(function(playlist) {
            playlist.singleCategory.forEach(function(single) {
                  if(single.id==singleId) {
                    dfd.resolve(single);
                  }
                });

           });

          return dfd.promise
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/h4msqT?p=preview)**

Comment: thank you for the answer, i understand your code. thanks. I was looking to solve this in other direction. if you didn't update your code i would take days to figure this out